# Excel find value which satisfies values from another two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
col1       col2     col3

26.03.2020 163,35    a
27.03.2020 153       a 
02.04.2020 153,12    v 
29.03.2020 153,12    b 
30.03.2020 141       a 
31.03.2020 142       v 
01.04.2020 137       c 
02.04.2020 168       a 
03.04.2020 185       a 
02.04.2020 185       t 
05.04.2020 185       y
```

In a cell I want a value that shows col2 value where col1 = 02.04.2020 and col3= a, so I need to look up for col1 = 02.04.2020  (say G1) and col3= a (say G5).

I tried

```
=INDEX(col2; MATCH(1;(G1=col1)*(G5=col3),0)
```

However, got NA.

Comment: Can there be duplicates of for example `01.04.2020` and `c`? And if so, should all results be listed?

Comment: @johnmayer Your formula works. Just enter it as array formula with ```ctrl``` + ```shift``` + ```enter```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of array entered formula try:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,G1,C:C,G5)
```

Other variants could be `MAXIFS` or `MINIFS` if one has access.